# create_engine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'engine_opts

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

app was running fine yesterday at home on **a different system **when i tried to run it on the different system ( **freshly installed everything** ) - *so i assume that this error is just for the latest version only.*

the goal is to connect the user in session to a second database

**i got this error:**
`create_engine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'engine_opts'`

**My current code:**

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgres:// ****" #main database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = "True"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = "None" #i didnt have that line in my system 
before i've just added it in attempt of fixing this issue

db = SQLAlchemy(app,session_options={"autoflush": False})


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    x = 'postgres://*****' #secondary database for user in session only.
    engine = db.create_engine(x)

return ''
```

Things I've tried :

**checking the library page :** [flask_SQLAlchemy Library](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/?highlight=engine_opts)

all i found about it was this:

> **create_engine**(*sa_url, engine_opts*) Override this method to have final
>   say over how the SQLAlchemy engine is created.
>
> In most cases, you will want to use 'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS' config
>   variable or set engine_options for SQLAlchemy().

after googling around i saw some examples and none of them worked.

**Attempt #01 :**

`db.create_engine(DB_URL,**engine_opts)`

*Output:*

> NameError: name 'engine_opts' is not defined

**Attempt #02 :**

`db.create_engine(DB_URL,**db.engine_opts)`

*Output:*

> AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'engine_opts'

**Attempt #03 :**

`db.create_engine(DB_URL,engine_opts='None')`

*Output:*

> TypeError: create_engine() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

**Attempt #04 :**

`db.create_engine(DB_URL,engine_opts=None)`

> TypeError: create_engine() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType

**Attempt #05 :**

`db.create_engine(xDB,db.engine_opts='None')`

System crashes **"didnt even run"** :

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

**Attempt #06 :**

`db.create_engine(xDB,{'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS': None})`

*Output:*

```
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\project1\app.py", line 175, in test
    engine = db.create_engine(xDB,{'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS': None})
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 966, in create_engine
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 435, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 632, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

**Attempt #07 :**

after installing `psycopg2` based on #Attempt06

`db.create_engine(xDB,{'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS': None})`

*Output:*

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS' sent to create_engine(), using configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

Comment: `None` should not be a string, it's a python object so leave it unquoted

Comment: @roganjosh TypeError: create_engine() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I've just added it , please refer to attempt #06 ` import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'`

Comment: Install psycopg2.

Comment: @IljaEverilä TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS' sent to create_engine(), using configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling a method **that you're not supposed to call**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i'm very dis-pointed in your rational decision , I have 2 laptops right next to each other  ( both are windows 10 ) , i have the application in a flash drive to make sure the exact same code run on both of them , my personal laptop runs the code fine , the others raise that error about "engine_opts" , i never thought someone with a respected rep. like yourself would judge a situation that fast ...

thank you for your input ..

Comment: @JRick that you can actually *call* a method in Python does not mean that you're *supposed* to call that method. In any case, the culprit is probably different versions of libraries - try `pip list` on both machines.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i know its probably because of the different versions of the libraries and i've mentioned that assumption 2nd line  of this post

Comment: i will check both versions and come back

Comment: I've told you already that the Flask-SQLAlchemy for this problem is like using a jackhammer to fix your laptop.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yea you did mention that but you never explained why ,  for all i know flask_sqlAlchemy is just a wrapper to SQLAlchemy , anyway i have checked the versions of both laptops ((( the not working ones ))) Flask_SQLAlchemy (2.4.0) / SQLAlchemy (1.3.3) , (((((( the working laptop ))))))Flask-SQLAlchemy(2.3.2) / SQLAlchemy(1.2.11) .... i should also mention that on that laptop i have like 2 columns of  libraries which probably part of "anaconda" or or other libraries i used on different projects.

Comment: is it possible to just down grade the current versions ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193596/discussion-between-j-rick-and-antti-haapala).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in conclusion :

`db.create_engine(DB_URL,{})` worked for me.

**Explaining why:**

the version of `flask_SQLAlchemy` i have on my own pc was `2.3.2`

fresh installed version was `2.4.0`

which has that feature , you can read it right there. [flask_SQLAlchemy - Changes
Version 2.4.0](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/changelog/#version-2-3-2)

- Make engine configuration more flexible ([#684](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/684))

> which have changed the way we create new engine.
>   before `db.create_engine(DB_URL)` was enough

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. And I fixed it.

Try:

```
from SQLAlchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URI)
```

rather than :

```
import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.create_engine(URI)
```